# How can i do a shortcut on Tinymce

Tags: jquery, tinymce

I'm using an editor called Tinymce, and i would like to insert an shortcut there, but i dont know how to do it, because my code doesn't work there, does anyone here ever used tinymce?

i want to show a message when the escape is clicked...

Code here:

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
    $('#txtareavalue').on('keydown', function (event) {
        if (event.which === 27) {
            alert('teste');
            event.preventDefault();
            return false;
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the TinyMCE documentation, which can be found here:

[http://www.tinymce.com/wiki.php/API3:event.tinymce.Editor.onKeyPress](http://www.tinymce.com/wiki.php/API3%3aevent.tinymce.Editor.onKeyPress)

```
// Adds an observer to the onKeyPress event using tinyMCE.init
tinyMCE.init({
   ...
   setup : function(ed) {
      ed.onKeyPress.add(function(ed, e) {
          console.debug('Key press event: ' + e.keyCode);
          //Put your on('keydown') code in here
      });
   }
});
```

Always take a look at the documentation :) that's what it's there for.